# Google Drive API via Service Account - Storage quota exceeded

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a google service account (Owned by me), which has been given access to another users Google Drive Account (Owned by someone else - Standard 15GB storage).  They granted full access to a single folder under their G-Drive account, and I can see that the SP has full access to the folder when using the googleapiclient python package.

I have a process that lists all the files within that folder, and overwrites some of them based on new/incoming data from an external source.  Here is what I see:

- Files that are very small (few KB to few MB) let me overwrite them over and over again, with no issues.  I do not see any version history, which I kind of expected to see.
- Files over 100MB seem to have an issue with hitting that quota. It doesn't matter if the file is already sitting on the server and I am overwriting it, or if I just remove the file completely and try and upload it. Oddly enough, I don't hit this every time and I have no issue actually uploading the file from Python as I am using multipart/resumable.
- When I get this quota error, I can still log into the google UI and manually upload files to that drive just fine.  No errors.
- When I log into the google drive account from a UI, I can see there are 0 bytes used for "Storage", even if I have 15 or so small-ish files in "My Drive".

So my questions are:

1. Do Service Accounts have a transfer quota?  I know for sure the Drive is not full, but I still get that quota limit with bigger files.
2. Are there differences between "My Drive" and "Storage" that I need to account for, such as impersonating a given user?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the error that you get? Also, please share a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: The error is in title - but the full error is: 
"googleapiclient.errors.ResumableUploadError: <HttpError 403 when requesting None returned "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded.". Details: "[{'message': "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded.", 'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'storageQuotaExceeded'}]">"

I am pretty sure I have figured it out - its an ownership issue. Even though the SP is the transporter of the data, its "owned" by the SP, so it goes against the SP's 15GB of storage, and not the users storage.

Comment: Are you using impersonation with your service account? That way files will not be owned by the service account.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an SA working with a public gmail account.  My understanding is that you can only do impersonation if you are a paid google customer, and the domain is a non-gmail domain. I did get around this issue though, by:

1. No more SA, as it didn't seem flexible enough for my need.
2. Instead I stood up a Desktop app, which was OAuth.
3. Using the credentials.json file that I got from point 2, I have a python script that will attempt to auth a given user, and store the results as a token.pickle file.
4. From that point, I can re-up the token on each daily run.

Comment: I was very hesitant in using this above approach b/c I assumed the token would expire and there would be no programatic way to get a new token (Meaning, I don't want to have to grant google permissions again), but that doesn't seem to be the case so far.  Once I have the pickle file, the content is being updated on each daily run. So far, so good.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done, which seems to be working, so far:

```
def get_service_user(api_name, api_version, scopes):
creds = None

if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
    with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    # Assuming here that once we have done the "grant" once as a real user, this file can then be moved to where its running, and update automatically.
    # User will need to run script locally and collect token.pickle file / give to person automating this thing.
    # Or if this runs in a UI, the back end process can just store for a given user.
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", scopes)
        # Can't run local server on Databricks. If the user changes, you must run this locally, authenticate with google, and store this file back in DBFS (location above)
        # Uncomment this blow "creds" section to run locally.
        # creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        print("The token can't be refreshed.  Please run this code locally and generate a new pickle file")
        exit(0)

    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open("token.pickle", 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

# return Google Drive API service
service = build(api_name, api_version, credentials=creds)
return service
```